# What is the purpose of multiple "catch" blocks in exception handling

Tags: exception, runtime-error

1. Why we need multiple "catch" blocks even though we can write one generic
   exception?
2. Is that important to know all the exception types and their purposes to make a good piece of code?

   I googled a lot but still have confusions in exception handling. Any good example?

**Generic Exception:**

```
try{
//some code
}
catch(Exception e){
//print e
}
//that's it.
```

**Multiple catches**

```
try{
//some code
}
catch(IOException e){
}
catch(SQLException e){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several advantages of using multiple exceptions:

1. General exceptions will not let you know the exact root cause of the issue especially if many steps/checks involved in a method implementation.  Also, If the exception occurs due to various reasons, you need to throw the different types of exceptions from your caller method implementation.

Eg: You can throw custom exceptions.

**Here is your service code:**

```
    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
      {
      throw InvalidUserNameException();
      }
      if(!IsInternetAvaialable()) 
      {
      throw NoInternetAvailableException()
      }
      else
      {
      //Implement though your login process and if need use various custom exceptions or throw the exception if occurs.
      }
    }

    public class InvalidUserNameException : Exception
    { 
      public InvalidUserNameException()
      {
      }

      public InvalidUserNameException(string message)
        : base(message)
      {
      }

      public InvalidUserNameException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
      {
      }
   }
```

**Caller Method:**

```
try {
  ...
} catch(InvalidUserNameException e) {
  // Show Alert Message here
} catch(NoInternetAvaibleException e) {
  // Show Alert Message with specific reason
}
catch(Exception e) {
  // Other Generic Exception goes here
}
```

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions

Comment: Hmmm, this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why we need multiple "catch" blocks even though we can write one generic exception?**

Sometimes you might need to specify what causes the problem.

For example,

```
try {
  ...
} catch(IOException e) {
  // Print "Error: we cannot open your file"
} catch(SQLException e) {
  // Print: "Error: we cannot connect to the database"
}
```

With different errors, users can understand what went wrong easily.

If we go with

```
try {
  ...
} catch(Exception e) {
  // Print "Error: " + e.
}
```

It's harder for the users to figure out what went wrong.

Also, we can send the users to different pages accordingly to the error if we use multiple `catch`-es.

---

**2.Is that important to know all the exception types and their purposes to make a good piece of code?**

Personally, I would go with important exceptions such as IO, DB, etc. that can cause serious trouble. For others, I would catch with general exception.

Comment: It really depends on the code. I normally go with the exceptions stated in the docs and relate to my program. Those should be enough.